# C# Why i can't send a request with my url?

Tags: c#, html

Hi i need to know why my url don't take request but when i ping him it's work.

```
static async void check(string ip)
{
   string url = "http://" + ip + "/";
   try
   {
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      Console.WriteLine("\n{0} ==> OK\n", url);
      Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
   }
   catch (HttpRequestException e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\n{0} ==> Exception Caught!", url);
      Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
   }
}
```

**Output:**
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.dll
http://192.168.0.236/ ==> Exception Caught!
Message :There was an error when the request was sent.

*On the HTML website:*

**General:**
Request URL: http://192.168.0.236/setup.html

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 200 OK

Remote Address: 192.168.0.236:80

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response Header:**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252

Server: Volumic

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate

Pragma: no-cache

Connection: close

**Request Header:**
GET /setup.html HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.0.236

Connection: keep-alive

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.52

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9

Referer: http://192.168.0.236/

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6

Cookie: sessionToken=48699711

**Can someone help me understand where the problem of my url comes from?**

Comment: It seems you got a 200 status code. What were you expecting?

Comment: Did you miss the "setup.html" part in your `url` variable?

Comment: `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` could be hiding the actual error.

Comment: It's a 200 status code yes but i want to know if it's my algo or my url that doesn't works. And where it is because the "Response Header:" is good so i really don't know.

Comment: @KlausGütter i don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Check if external traffic (internet) can access your server's port 80 ? When you browse the IP address it should return the iis welcome page or the application that you installed (on port 80)

Comment: Yes it's the same taht works on internet but not with my algo...